# Problems with getting jquery dialog box to work

Tags: jquery, dialog

In the code below the Dialog Box will not open when the button is clicked. Also, the contents of the dialog box show up on page load and are not hidden before I click the button.

What is going wrong?

This code is close to the code right off of the jquery ui site.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../websites/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
    <script>
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include jQuery UI which is what delivers the dialog widget.

```
<script src="../websites/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

When you have both included in the page, it works fine as in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cA7H2/)**.